# How to send data from android to java application on server

Tags: java, android, mysql

Hi I want to send data from my android app to server and store in the Mysql database. But I want to use REST method to send the data and I want to create a Java app on the server side that will show the data in table format .
I have created the android app but don't know how to upload data using REST.  The data which I want to send is latitude and longitude of current location.
And after refreshing the java page new data will be viewed on the page.
Please tell me how to do this task.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some framework to communicate with a server. I think retrofit is the best choice for REST API: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

But you can try the Volley. Or the HttpUrlConnection and DefaultHttpClient in android sdk.

Answer (score 0):

This is a big question that would need more space than here to cover.  To get started you could try looking at the [spring boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) or [drop wizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/) frameworks for creating your REST service.

Coursera also has a course [programming web services](https://www.coursera.org/course/mobilecloudprogram) that might help you get started.

Alternatively, there are services like [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) that look after the backend process for you.